# Fourier transformation: $t\cdot\sigma(t)e^{-t}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation

$$f(t) = t\cdot\sigma(t)e^{-t}, \text{where}\,\sigma(t)\text{ is the unit step function}$$

I thought about using the convolution theorem because we know that

$F[\sigma(t)e^{-t}](\omega) = \frac{1}{1+j\omega}$

However, I'm not sure what the transformation of $g(t) = t$ is, and so I'm not sure how to proceed. Also I've been trying to google it but I couldn't find anything.

I'd like to transform $f(t)$ without needing to derive any transformation, i.e. by using [common transformations](http://uspas.fnal.gov/materials/11ODU/FourierTransformPairs.pdf) (and not the last one, that's too easy).

Comment: Hint: multiplication with $t$ in time domain will imply differentiation in frequency domain $\omega$.

Comment: @RakeshBalhara Ok, so when I take the derivative of $\frac{1}{1+j\omega}$, with respect to $\omega$, I do in fact get the right answer. How did you know multiplication with $t$ in time domain implied a differentiation in frequency domain?

Comment: proof of this can be found in any text on Fourier Transform. I would refer Walter Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis, chapter 9